# CSS. Menu text color not changing on hover OR menu text color changing

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created a sub menu for a website using CSS. But I want to change menu text color  on mouse hover. But when I change the code to 'make it work' the other text color in the sub menu changes.

**Problem 1 CSS code**

```
ul ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}
ul#header_menu {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
ul li:hover a {  

    color: #1583BE;

    transition: color .16s linear;
}
ul li:hover {
    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
ul ul {
    background: white; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; 
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}
```

**Problem 2 CSS code**

```
ul ul {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}
ul#header_menu {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
ul li:hover a {  

    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}
ul li:hover {
    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
ul ul {
    background: white; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%; 
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}
```

I have added jsfiddle now.

**Problem 1 jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/LsjCS/

**Problem 2 jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/5pjUu/

I have tried to make it work but not successfully.
Sorry for my, sometimes, poor English.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you post the HTML code you use as well?

Comment: debugging with only CSS is sometimes possible but it requires much time, no one may feel free to scan all the CSS lines... the best way (for the answerers) is try making some fiddle and post the link in your question. Visit the http://jsfiddle.net to get started.

Comment: I've added jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked from your first fiddle. The problem is where you apply the `:hover` on. So if you change there this part (line 22 of the CSS)

```
ul li:hover a {  

    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}
```

to this

```
ul li a:hover {  

    color: #1583BE;
    transition: color .16s linear;
}
```

If I understood your question correctly, then that solves your problem.

Comment: If you would just help me with one more little thing?
As you can see I used a transition to make to color 'fade in'. Do you know where I can add a transition (and how to) to make the drop down menu appear more gradually?

Comment: I found this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820403/css-menu-transition Should work! :)